# Is it needed to specify a BlockingQueue for QueuedThreadPool if ServerConnector is already configured with AcceptQueueSize?

Tags: java, server, jetty, threadpool, jetty-9

While creating a Jetty Server and Jetty ServerConnector,

```
QueuedThreadPool pool = new QueuedThreadPool(minThread,maxThread,new BlockingArrayQueue());
Server server = new Server​(pool);
/*rest code blah blah*/
ServerConnector servConn = ServerConnector​(server, acceptors, selectors, sslContextFactory);
/*rest code blah blah */
int acceptQueueSize = getAcceptQueueSize();
servConn.setAcceptQueueSize(acceptQueueSize);
/*rest code blah blah */
```

What is the relation between *"BlockingArrayQueue for QTP"* and *"setting the setAcceptQueueSize for ServerConnector"*?
if BlockingArrayQueue is set with maxCapacity parameter in constructor then will the acceptQueueSize affect this maxCapacity ?

(in the above code I have used the basic constructor of BlockingArrayQueueSize, please check below links for the other constructors. Please refer the below links for other referenced classes in above code block)

- ServerConnector(https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.27.v20200227/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.html)
- QueuedThreadPool (https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/util/thread/QueuedThreadPool.html)
- BlockingArrayQueue(https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/9.4.27.v20200227/org/eclipse/jetty/util/BlockingArrayQueue.html)

Answer (score 1):

The QueuedThreadPool constructor parameter for `BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue` exists for embedded systems users that need to tweak their Jetty environment for extremely low system utilization and/or JVM limitations.

Jetty can (and does) run on embedded systems which have only 16 MB of RAM.

If you are using OpenJDK or any derivative, then don't change the queue type unless you fully (and I mean 100% understand the behavior of the JVM you are running on on the hardware that it will run on).  Using the default `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` implementation is nearly always recommended.

If you are considering using some kind of alternative / tweaked / configured `BlockingQueue<Runnable>` to implement some kind of limitation of load or resource utilization then you are going down the wrong path.   Jetty is not a 1 thread per 1 connection style of Container, a single connection can result in the usage of multiple different threads through the lifespan of that single connection.  Your use of various technologies within Jetty can also alter the threading demands you place on Jetty. It is very easy for you to have a single connection, with a single request, use multiple threads to service that request (all dependent on what you decide to do during that request).

Comment: You don't want to deal with this at the threading / thread pool / connector / etc level.  Use the QoSFilter and/or DoSFilter to manage resources on a live system.  One that can actually always respond to the HTTP request (even with "server busy" style responses).